# IBM RTC API - Adding files to change sets

Tags: java, api, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

Basically I'm experimenting with the IBM Rational Team Concert Plain Java Client API, and I'm stuck at adding operations to change sets.

I create a new change set, retrieve the Operation factory and then I'd like to add a new file from the local machine file system (might be a new file of a project).

```
val changeSetHandle = workspaceConnection.createChangeSet(component, null)
val operationFactory = workspaceConnection.configurationOpFactory()
val saveOperation = operationFactory.save(...)
```

I do not understand how to to obtain an `IVersionable` handle to submit to the `save()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/176386/creating-new-file-without-commiting-it-to-a-changeset-using-java-api) which shows an example of `IVersionable`:

```
// Create a new file and give it some content
IFileItem file = (IFileItem) IFileItem.ITEM_TYPE.createItem();
file.setName("file.txt");
file.setParent(projectFolder);

// Create file content.
IFileContentManager contentManager = FileSystemCore.getContentManager(repository);
IFileContent fileContent = contentManager.storeContent(
              "UTF-8",
              FileLineDelimiter.LINE_DELIMITER_LF,
              new VersionedContentManagerByteArrayInputStreamPovider(BYTE_ARRAY),
              null,
              null);

file.setContent(fileContent);
file.setContentType(IFileItem.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT);
file.setFileTimestamp(new Date());

workspaceConnection.configurationOpFactory().save(file);
```

However, this is not enough:

> `IConfigurationOpFactory` is used to update a repository workspace by adding changes to a change set.
>   The usage pattern is to get a workspace connection, create a bunch of save operations, then run `IWorkspaceConnection#commit()` on those ops.
>   Calling `save()` without committing the change drops the op onto the stack for the garbage collector to gobble up. ;)

Comment: See also https://jazz.net/forum/questions/180073/trying-to-get-a-collection-of-ifileitems-from-a-known-workspace-and-a-known-sandbox for existing files.

Comment: Thanks, really! I find the RTC API have a steep learning curve, seems learning will take months. Also, the documentation is a bit spare (maybe I still do not understand how it is organized)

Comment: @LppEdd Yes, the maintainers of the product might answer there rather than here.